# Does California vowel shift occur in bilingual Spanish speakers?

Tags: english, vowels, spanish, bilingualism

I know that recently there has been a lot of research done on the California vowel shift being a key part of a California accent for younger kids who have grown up there.

Knowing that there is a large Spanish speaking population especially in southern California I was wondering if this phenomenon has at all affected bilingual children’s Spanish accent who grew up speaking both english and Spanish in California. Do their vowels shift in Spanish as well, or is it not relevant in Spanish language?

Comment: Just an speculative comment while waiting for an informed answer. Spanish vowel system is very different from the English one: only five vowels, clearly distinct and unequivocally matching the five vowel letters in alphabet. Therefore, such a vowel shift seems less likely. Confusion of the many English vowels into only a few is more likely https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-native_pronunciations_of_English#Spanish . Furthermore the vowels affected by California vowel shift aren't those best matching Spanish vowels.